# Unable to cast object of type System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal to type Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.IClaimsPrincipal

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-web-roles

I am developing one MVC4 application which authenticate corp domain users using ADFS and i have written the code and i am getting the error like below, am i not getting claims ?

System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal' to type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.IClaimsPrincipal'.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {

            IClaimsPrincipal principal = (IClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
            IClaimsIdentity identity = (IClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(identity.Claims[0].Value.Split('@')[0]))
            {
                ViewData["Message"] = string.Format("You are email is :{0}", identity.Claims[0].Value.Split('@')[0]);

            }
            else
            {
                ViewData["Message"] = "You are not getting any claims";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Something wrong.";
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

What you observe is result of mixing .NET 3.5 WIF (Microsoft.IdentityModel) and WIF 4.0 (System.IdentityModel & System.Security).
What I suggest is:

1. Remove reference to [Microsoft.IdentityModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.aspx).* assemblies in your project
2. Add reference to [System.IdentityModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145031%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) & System.IdentityModel.Services assemblies
3. Fix using statements
4. Fix references to Microsoft.IdentityModel in your Web.Config

Do a backup copy of your project before doing this, because, if you haven't done this before, you might end up with a lot of error and not working code. But the main idea is that you have to get rid of all and any `Microsoft.IdentityModel` references and you will be good.

Answer (score 2):

I am able resolved this issue as per astaykov suggestion and i changed the code like below,

```
using System.Security.Claims;
var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;         

        foreach (var claim in identity.Claims)
        {
            if (claim.Type.Contains("EmailAddress"))
            {
                ViewBag.EmailName = claim.Value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This worked for me by changing the code from 'claim.Type.Contains' to 'claim.ClaimType.Contains' in the foreach loop